# What is a structural framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS by going through the documentation and came across below statement that tells about Angular JS:

[AngularJS is a structural framework for dynamic web apps](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction)

I hear AngularJS as a javascript framework, but what does it mean when they say `structural framework`, can someone please explain this?

Comment: Something like Modular?

Comment: Somebody just made that up. It's not important.

Comment: Tushar & Pointy, Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular can be called a structural framework in the sense that it applies 'structure' to your project.

With your UI code in html, logical code for controllers, directives, services & factories all split in their own 'sections' in your javascript files instead of clumped up together (which would/could make it hard to distinct them) you could say that you have more 'structure' in your project. This splitting up makes your code more modular as Tushar also mentioned.

Other than that, I imagine it was just added in that sentence to make it sound more fancy.